# Rigorous textbook on the DTFT

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I am an engineering student who is slowly branching into applied mathematics. While I can find plenty of good textbooks on the rigorous treatment of the Fourier Transform itself (including functional analysis and the Schwartz space and the result of this for the Fourier Transform) but I am having difficulty in finding an equivalent for the Discrete Time Fourier Transform (DTFT). Does anyone know of books that rigorously handle the DTFT, particularly on the convergence of functions that are not absolutely summable and its DTFT?